# jQuery UI Drag/Drop does not work in FF

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, list, connect

I've been looking all over the place, but I haven't landed an answer yet. Is the current jQuery UI 1.8-1.8.2 supports Firefox 3+? I have 3.6.3 installed, but the example on their websites works for my IE7, IE8, Chrome, but not Firefox.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

Is anyone else having this problem? It is not PC specific either because both of my PC at home and at work is having the same problem.

Comment: it's working fine here on FF 3.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed my FF, removed my saved profile and reinstalled FF. Everything works now.